# Querying documents by sub-sub document id

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema's:

```
var Post = new mongoose.Schema({
 'responses': [Response]
});

var Response = new mongoose.Schema({
 'question': Question
});

var Question = new mongoose.Schema({
 'id': 12345
});
```

How would I query for **POSTS** that contain **RESPONSES** that match a certain **QUESTION** _id. For example: 12345?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the query you are looking for

```
const _id = 'some object id'
Post.find({ 'responses.question._id' : _id }).then((posts) => {
   console.log(posts);
}).catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. Responses is an array, which could have something to do with it.

Comment: what would you like to get from your query?, maybe I did not understand it